# Adblock filter parser

Tags: sniffer, adblock

I'm writing a network sniffer (e.g. wireshark) and I want to ignore traffic generated from advertisements and trackers.
For this matter I want to load Easylist (AdBlock plus list of filters) to my sniffer and use it from there.
I wonder if there's an open source parser that reads adblock filters ?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off blocking requests to advert related hosts by using a hosts file [like this one](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt). The approach you are thinking of has quite a few disadvantages and is likely not practical. The Adblock Plus filter lists are not really designed to be used in this way.

That said there *is* a library you could look into, [libadblockplus](https://github.com/adblockplus/libadblockplus). It's opensource along with the [rest of the Adblock plus code](https://github.com/adblockplus) as well so if you want to give this a go maybe having a look through some of the code would be useful.